# low rate of stereo prosilica cameras for face_detector

Tags: ros, syncronization, face-detection

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using a pair of prosilica cameras on care-o-bot, receiving images (left, right, disparity) at rate of about 2 hz, few synchronized triples, which leads to use _approximate_sync:=True _queue_size:=10 in stereo_proc and stereo_view

now face_detector is not working for this pair, while it works fine with a recorded bag video (test), has anyone any idea? suggession, please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9261/low-rate-of-stereo-prosilica-cameras-for-face_detector/) by [Reza](https://answers.ros.org/users/126/reza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2011-03-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-02**:
What is the network connection between the nodes and what else is runnong over that connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sorry should correct part of my last comment as below:

I downgraded bag playing rate to 2 hz to simulate real camera, face_detector is working fine, so images (camera) synchronization should be a matter not the low rate.

---

Originally posted by [Reza](https://answers.ros.org/users/126/reza/) with karma: 116 on 2011-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reza](https://answers.ros.org/users/126/reza/) on 2011-03-03**:
rostopic hz /stereo/left/image_rect is about 2.2    rostopic hz /stereo/right/image_rect is about 2.4      rostopic hz /stereo/disparity is about 1.6